# Hi-res pic found its way into Careers sidebar ad

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, advertising

I just noticed a sidebar advert in Careers loading super-slowly - suspect it is because it's a [3508 x 2480 px JPEG](http://press.which.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/which_logo_hi_res.jpg)! Can a techie fix please? `:-)`

Comment: Which ad? Tell me. WHICH?!?

Comment: I don't think this should be "fixed". The level of detail available is very important for images as complex as that one. If we were to halve the resolution in each direction, the nuances would be utterly lost.

Comment: Hmm, this is the worst offender, but there are a lot of company logos over a a megapixel, even though they're displayed with `max-width: 180px`. Automatic rescaling would be a good idea.

Comment: It's also weird that some company images are being hotlinked from the company's site, rather than being hosted directly by Stack Exchange. (Another example: [Hailo](http://hailocab.com/wp-content/themes/hailo/images/consumer/logo.png)

Comment: @Bart: if you stare at it long enough, the answer will come to you - but be patient, it's quite subtle!

Comment: Unless they put in infrastructure to automatically process and store images before serving them, this can't be fixed on SE's side. The image is served by the company

Comment: @Asad: I should think advertisers have a control panel they can set the URL in, yes. But, as Korneel says, the Careers site could read it in, shrink it to a suitable size and cache it on their own servers for a couple of hours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for that! This has been fixed, the image now comes in at a whopping 5.99 KB. We'll look at the other images as well, and make sure that the size of the image specified is double checked. And maybe even do some of that fancy automatic rescaling down the line...